# Scala: How to implement functions without names like List(1,2,3)(3)

Tags: scala

I'm asking myself how to implement functions like the list access function in
`List(1,2,3)(3)` for my own classes in scala. What I found out so far is that they are NOT treated as normal functions, since `List(1,2,3).(3)` won't work (Identifier after . expected). However, I was unable to use google to find out what these functions are called.

Is it possible to implement such a syntax for arbitrary classes? How is that concept called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

`foo(bar)` is syntax sugar for `foo.apply(bar)`.

Just implement an `apply` method.

Comment: So, List(...)(3) gets substituted by List(...).apply(3) and the first call is no language concept by itself, right? Thanks for you answer, will accept it as soon as possible!

Comment: Actually `List(1, 2, 3)` is also a call to the method `apply` of the object `List`.